# Apache connection refused outside of localhost

Tags: apache

I'm running Ubuntu on vmware under windows 10, I set up and configured my apache to these configurations:

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<Directory /> ... stuff ... Require all granted </Directory>
```

VirtualHost1

```
 <Directory ...>
....
AllowOverride All 
Require all granted
</>
```

When I call the website from within the ubuntu on my vm it's reached fine, but when I call this site from my windows vm host machine my conn. gets refused.

This is my ubuntu hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 test.com www.test.com
```

this is my windows hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 test.com www.test.com
```

**** All the listings here are approximate, so don't quote mistakes in code, apache restarts just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all intent and purposes, a virtual machine is not the same as the host machine. Their network is totally separate.

If your virtual network is `bridged`, you need to access your ubuntu web server from it's public interface, usually `eth0`. This means, you will need to edit hosts file in windows to point `www.test.com` to the public ip address of ubuntu.

If your virtual network is `NAT`ted, you need to configure port-forwarding. I recommend using the same port numbers, if possible, for ease of use. You can keep the windows host table the same way you already have.

In both cases, the apache web server should listen on the public interface.

Comment: @TimAkgayev - There are several reasons you will get a `403` or `FORBIDDEN` error. If `SELINUX` is enabled and your html data does not have the correct context, you will get this error. To check if SELINUX is enabled, run `getenforce`. To see the context of your html data directory run `ls -Z /path/to/www/data`. If directory permission or access control list do not allow the owner of the process `httpd` you will also get this error. These are just 2 of the many reasons.

Comment: I had to install seliunx-utils to use that command, getenforce returns disabled, running ls -Z in my www/test.com/html folder yields a question mark next to the index.html edit: so I also have to be the owner of apache2 process?

Comment: I just saw the error message in your comment on the other answer. It is telling you that the owner of the httpd process can't read the index.html file. Is the file and the parent directories accessible by apache? Try this `cd /; sudo -u apache -s /bin/bash -c cat /var/www/html/index.html`.

Comment: So how do I find this process location to set the owner?

Comment: The process owner is defined in `httpd.conf`. Look for the keyword `User` and `Group`.

Comment: the command you recommended says no user "apache", is that command just adding setting owner of index to apache? Shouldn't I be setting the whole directory?

Comment: You need to replace the user `apache` in the command I gave you with the correct user you have for your httpd listener. Sorry I assumed that you are familiar with `LAMP`. I should have spelled it out.

Comment: All right I got it to work, I changed the group on the www dirctory to www-data. Thanks for your help )

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how you have configured you virtual host networking settings.

The 127.0.0.1 refers to you windows host on the windows machine and 127.0.0.1 refers to the ubuntu host on the virtual machine. The concept localhost (127.0.0.1) is always **local** host and should not leave the actual network interface (virtual or not). You need to contact you virtual host on virtually "external" ip-number from windows.

You can get the ubuntu ip-number by running "ifconfig" in a shell.

Best regards

Jørgen

Comment: Thank you that worked, however now I'm getting Forbidden /index.html, I checked the error log it says "file permissions deny server access". I have the whole /var/www directory chown to myself recursively and also have 751 permission on it. Should I also own the apache process to myself?

Comment: Also as a side question, in my apache2.conf (hppd.conf) do I absolutely have to have the / directory grant access to all? (right now I do, but I was wondering if it's a safety issue)

Comment: The filesystem entries should be owned by the apache process owner or have at least global read (**1) and global read and execute (**5) for the directories. It is not advisable to run the apache process as a regular user as it might be a serious security issue.

Comment: I would suggest to try with changing the group of the /var/www to the apache process group or try with 755 permissions.

Comment: Thank you the problem was fixed in the above comment, but yes I did indeed have to set my www dir to www-data group to fix it.